# Транзакции firebase, android app

Tags: android, firebase

Так что у меня есть. Есть клиент в виде android приложения. Есть бд firebase, откуда клиент берёт данные. В бд у меня есть узел с одинаковыми подузлами, которые представляют из себя набор данных для опроса (варианты голосования и их процентное соотношение, впрочем это не важно). Главное то, что проголосовать в одном опросе, может ограниченное количество пользователей. При этом приложение погружает рандомный опрос из списка имеющихся. И вот теперь суть проблемы. Как сделать так, чтобы если один пользователь получил данные с бд об одном опросе, другие пользователи не могли получать этот опрос. Все что мне пришло в голову, это сделать это с помощью транзакции, и то я не уверен, что это сработает. Вот к примеру пользователь запустил транзакции по одному из опросов, получил данные опроса. И как мне удерживать транзакции до тех пор пока пользователь не ткнет на экране по одному из вариантов голосования, а потом уже запушить изменения в транзакции. Выносить что ли транзакции в отдельный поток? Ведь если я поставлю в транзакции после получения данных какой-то цикл ожидания, то экран заблокируется, ну то есть я заблокирую главный поток. Как решить эту проблему?

Comment: Как вариант, добавить к опросу поля inUse(bool) и inUseStartDate(date). Когда пользователь получает этот опрос, ставить их в true и текущую дату, соответственно. И другим пользователям не выдавать этот вопрос, пока он не станет inUse == false или не пройдёт какое-то кол-во времени. Ну это первое, что пришло в голову.

Comment: Не прокатит такой вариант. Свободный опрос могут получить сразу несколько клиентов.